# Taking a student loan without any history of credit?

Tags: loans, student-loan

I'm 18 years old and I'm considering taking a student loan as all the alternatives are exhausted and I can't continue my undergraduate studies without a loan. I don't have a history of credit and my father's credit isn't shiny as well if he wanted to be the co-signer. I still try and look for many options as possible. I'm willing to continue my education despite of all the costs I may incur. I know it's difficult for financial institutions to provide loans. I'm not a US citizen.

**What are my options to take a student loan without a co-signer?**

Grants and scholarships are unlikely and the money isn't sufficient to fund my entire studying period.

Comment: If you're already a college student, ask your school's financial aid office. They will know what programs are available to you, possibly including loans from the school itself. I presume you're also looking at on/near-campus jobs to provide additional income; the finaid folks may be able to make some suggestions there too.

Comment: Take heart. Most students are in a similar situation of being young and having almost no credit history. The student loan providers are used to dealing with this situation. You are not an outlier or unusual case for them because of this.

Comment: It's hard to find a job here and if I did, the paying rate is too low that will absolutely never suffices the minimum needs for surviving and I need to take into my account the years that will be spent on working.

Comment: where are you? and what is your citizenship?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, middle east, GCC countries.

Answer (score 1):

As unbelievable as it sounds, you can borrow a sick amount of money at age 18 with no cosigner and no credit.  You can get enough in loans to cover a MA in Art History at a private institution, which will cost you close to 300K.  After you are done you will be qualified to earn close to minimum wage.

BTW you are already have those same qualifications.

As the comment suggested the college's financial aid office will not only have info, but will also encourage you to take student loans.  You will need to fill out a FAFSA.  My daughter and two sons all attend college, debt free, and have the office pushing student loans and private lenders pushing credit cards.

You might want to check this out: [student loans](http://www.infowars.com/18-sobering-facts-about-the-unprecedented-student-loan-debt-crisis-in-the-united-states/).

While you may feel you have done so, you have probably not exhausted all possibilities.  The "education at all costs" might turn into curse more then a blessing.  Do you have a job?  What is precluding you from saving money for college?  Can you obtain a job that pays some portion of college?  How many scholarships have you applied for?  If the number is less than 200, you have not exhausted that possibility.

School and major choice is very important.  Starting with community college and staying away from private institutions is a key to obtaining an education without high cost.

Comment: I'm not a US-citizen and so what you said may not apply to me. But, I don't know if I could do that if I decided to study in the united states ? But education there is more expensive than the rest of the world. Probably after the U.K. But if decided to continue my education I may find a good job especially that I'm willing to study software engineering, but that only an assumption. Of course, if I found a part-time job, that would be much better.

Answer (score -2):

A US bank will normally only lend to someone who is a US citizen or a long-term resident.

You should talk to banks in your own country, whatever that is.